# undefined reference to `tensorflow::SessionOptions::SessionOptions()' when compiling Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, c++17, g++, tensorflow2.0, bazel

So I built the TF library to use it with the c++ API like this:

```
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow
cd tensorflow
git checkout v2.11.0

bazel build //tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so
bazel build //tensorflow:libtensorflow_framework.so
bazel build //tensorflow:install_headers
```

Then I tried to compile the following simple program:

```
#include <tensorflow/core/platform/env.h>
#include <tensorflow/core/public/session.h>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace tensorflow;

int main()
{
    Session* session;
    Status status = NewSession(SessionOptions(), &session);
    if (!status.ok()) {
        cout << status.ToString() << "\n";
        return 1;
    }
    cout << "Session successfully created.\n";
}
```

With the command:

```
g++ \
  -std=c++17 \
  -I./tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/include/ \
  -I./root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/68a62076e91007a7908bc42a32e4cff9/external/com_google_protobuf/src/ \ # yours will be different from _bazel_root/ to /external
  -L./tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/ \
  -ltensorflow_cc \
  -ltensorflow_framework \
  my_program.cpp -o my_program
```

But the following error message appears:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccPppSSw.o: in function `main':
my_program3.cpp:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `tensorflow::SessionOptions::SessionOptions()'
/usr/bin/ld: my_program3.cpp:(.text+0x4c): undefined reference to `tensorflow::NewSession(tensorflow::SessionOptions const&, tensorflow::Session**)'
/usr/bin/ld: my_program3.cpp:(.text+0x8a): undefined reference to `tsl::Status::ToString[abi:cxx11]() const'
/usr/bin/ld: my_program3.cpp:(.text+0x102): undefined reference to `tsl::Status::~Status()'
/usr/bin/ld: my_program3.cpp:(.text+0x16f): undefined reference to `tsl::Status::~Status()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccPppSSw.o: in function `tsl::core::RefCounted::~RefCounted()':
my_program3.cpp:(.text._ZN3tsl4core10RefCountedD2Ev[_ZN3tsl4core10RefCountedD5Ev]+0xf8): undefined reference to `tsl::internal::LogMessageFatal::LogMessageFatal(char const*, int)'
/usr/bin/ld: my_program3.cpp:(.text._ZN3tsl4core10RefCountedD2Ev[_ZN3tsl4core10RefCountedD5Ev]+0x120): undefined reference to `tsl::internal::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccPppSSw.o: in function `tensorflow::SessionOptions::~SessionOptions()':
my_program3.cpp:(.text._ZN10tensorflow14SessionOptionsD2Ev[_ZN10tensorflow14SessionOptionsD5Ev]+0x1c): undefined reference to `tensorflow::ConfigProto::~ConfigProto()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccPppSSw.o: in function `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >* tsl::internal::MakeCheckOpString<long, int>(long const&, int const&, char const*)':
my_program3.cpp:(.text._ZN3tsl8internal17MakeCheckOpStringIliEEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKT_RKT0_PKc[_ZN3tsl8internal17MakeCheckOpStringIliEEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKT_RKT0_PKc]+0x37): undefined reference to `tsl::internal::CheckOpMessageBuilder::CheckOpMessageBuilder(char const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: my_program3.cpp:(.text._ZN3tsl8internal17MakeCheckOpStringIliEEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKT_RKT0_PKc[_ZN3tsl8internal17MakeCheckOpStringIliEEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKT_RKT0_PKc]+0x61): undefined reference to `tsl::internal::CheckOpMessageBuilder::ForVar2()'
/usr/bin/ld: my_program3.cpp:(.text._ZN3tsl8internal17MakeCheckOpStringIliEEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKT_RKT0_PKc[_ZN3tsl8internal17MakeCheckOpStringIliEEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKT_RKT0_PKc]+0x7f): undefined reference to `tsl::internal::CheckOpMessageBuilder::NewString[abi:cxx11]()'
/usr/bin/ld: my_program3.cpp:(.text._ZN3tsl8internal17MakeCheckOpStringIliEEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKT_RKT0_PKc[_ZN3tsl8internal17MakeCheckOpStringIliEEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKT_RKT0_PKc]+0x8f): undefined reference to `tsl::internal::CheckOpMessageBuilder::~CheckOpMessageBuilder()'
/usr/bin/ld: my_program3.cpp:(.text._ZN3tsl8internal17MakeCheckOpStringIliEEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKT_RKT0_PKc[_ZN3tsl8internal17MakeCheckOpStringIliEEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKT_RKT0_PKc]+0xb6): undefined reference to `tsl::internal::CheckOpMessageBuilder::~CheckOpMessageBuilder()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Nevertheless when I check for symbols in libtensorflow_cc.so with:

```
nm -g ./tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/libtensorflow_cc.so | grep "tensorflow..SessionOptions"
```

The symbol appears to be there:

```
000000000ee12080 T _ZN10tensorflow14SessionOptionsC1Ev
000000000ee12080 T _ZN10tensorflow14SessionOptionsC2Ev
```

Any guess about what is happening there?

expected to be linked without issues

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that the issue was the order of the -l flags, the proper command is:

```
g++ \
  -std=c++17 \
  -I./tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/include/ \
  -I./root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/68a62076e91007a7908bc42a32e4cff9/external/com_google_protobuf/src/ \
  -L./tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/ \
  my_program.cpp -o my_program \
  -ltensorflow_cc \
  -ltensorflow_framework
```